# EF CTP4 lazy loading not playing ball

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading, poco

I'm using the CTP4 code first EF framework, but I'm having problems getting lazy loading to work.  Reading up on it, it should be simple, but it's just not

```
public class Folder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentFolderId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Folder> ChildFolders { get; set; }
}
```

In the model configuration:

```
HasMany(f => f.ChildFolders).WithOptional().HasConstraint((child, folder) => child.ParentFolderId == folder.Id);
```

However, when I do this:

```
Folder folder = context.Folders.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == 1);
```

folder.ChildPages is null....but it should be lazy loading it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this, actually: The empty constructor for "Folder" was marked internal, and although there were no hard failures, it seems this was enough to cause problems.

Comment: I've found that this can also happen when the class itself is marked internal.  In a project I've been working on today, I left off class visibility (leaving the classes internal), and lazy loading absolutely refused to work until I changed them to public.

Answer (score 0):

Is your context based on DbContext or ObjectContext? If it is ObjectContext then you have to turn on lazy loading in ContextOptions.